# I build pacman in game maker, how build ghost to chasing pacman like AI greedy

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-maker

need code please, this my code:

```
{
  if (hspeed == 0) 0
  { 

    if (random(3)<1 and place_free(x-4,y)) 
      { 
       hspeed = -4; 
       vspeed = 0;  }

    if (random(3)<1 and place_free(x+4,y))
      { hspeed =  4; vspeed = 0;}
```

Comment: Please, can be more specific about your trouble? Can you put the source code of your try, please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

pacman ghosts don't move at random directions; in pacman you don't even need to move by finite numbers like 4 and check for collisions; you should have a graph of all intersections and build the ai on that. 
Although from your question i deduce you lack the basics for separating what is seen by what happens in the background.

Hint: most games aren't what the user can see; tetris and minesweeper are just bidimensional arrays, pacman is a graph, card games are stacks and lists. The only "simple" game i can think of where what you see is exactly what happens is pong.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwhXIzNrb9w